# how to Distinguish Android physical menu button longPress and click without block the default optionMenu of Android

Tags: android

Now I want to custom the physical menu button with two actions: long press and click.

The question is that when I got the keyDown event, then android system will block my default option menu to show,just like below:

```
   onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
            event.startTracking();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
```

how to escape that ?  Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

openOptionMenu() is useful for me when onKeyUp() is called!

Answer (score 0):

You need to return false; returning true means "I've handled this event and I don't want anything else to handle it", which is blocking the Android system from reacting to it (by opening the menu). Returning false allows the system to continue to handle it. [Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29)

So just removing your "return" should do what you want:

```
onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        event.startTracking();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```